# ajax call Success block

Tags: jquery

```
getContent:function($obj){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $obj.url,
        dataType: "html",
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
        },
        success: function(html) {
            alert('hi');
            //getContent.data = html;
        },
        error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        }           
    });
},
```

In the above block I am not getting success so unable to execute the logic can I know the reason please? I am using AJAX call for the first time.

Comment: Firstly verify that your server side url is actually getting called.
When do you not add an alert in your error function

Comment: It is the incoming parameter isn't it

Comment: yes $obj is the incoming parameter I dont know which serverside url u meant the url i want call?

Answer (score 1):

In place of $obj.url give correct path, like if you calling any file than give exact file name like backend.php etc.,